# React render component

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


class LayoutContainer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>asdas</div>
    )}
}

ReactDOM.render(<LayoutContainer />, document.getElementById('gddmain'));
```

I have created webpack config file:

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");


const common_entry_point = path.resolve(__dirname, "resources", "assets");
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        home: path.resolve(common_entry_point, "react", "reactTest.js")
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: path.resolve(common_entry_point, "minjs")
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test:/.jsx?$/,loader:"babel-loader",exclude:"/node_modules/"}

        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [" ", ".", ".js", ".jsx", ".json"]
    },
    watch: true
}
```

The first, when I start to build I get an error 
"Unexpected error in `<LayoutContainer>`" .
How can I render this component.

Comment: You are returning a string. You might have to do `return <div>asdas</div>` instead (without the quotes).

Comment: If you have trouble configuring webpack and babel you may just use create-react-app

Comment: Your component is valid React syntax, and should render fine. Your webpack config is ugly, and there is probably something wrong with how you set it up. Are you naming your component with extension .jsx? Because that is all your loader is looking for. Here is proof your component renders fine https://codepen.io/DZuz14/pen/RLMVPX

Comment: Yeah, thanks I was naming my component extension jsx, but  found js files. Thanks  a lot